# Redirect the socket traffic on an application already executed

Tags: c, sockets, networking, frida

I am trying to understand how to change the IP/port of a socket used by an application, to get it to send its packets to me instead of the original recipient.

I saw that Frida API can help me to do that, but I want to understand how its done. Could someone explain to me how Frida is able to do that? It kind of blows my mind that it is able to slip so deeply into a program.

Comment: It presumably uses the `ptrace` facility to modify the the process memory.

Comment: Oh i didnt know about this function, it seems really powerful, thanks